# General mask for a telephone number?

Tags: telephony, standards

I'm making a web form and wanted to have a general template for a phone number.

In my experience every phone number might be represented in 13-digits format: xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx. For example the country code of some area in Switzerland is 0041, but the phone numbers contain 13-digits overall:

```
0041 44 995 1570 could be written as:
004 144 995 1570
```

However I can't find any proof of 13-digits format. I found a wikipedia entry https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164 and this seems to imply that the general phone number format is 15-digits, which I haven't seen my-self.

I'm not sure this question belongs to SuperUser though.

Comment: Nope there are short numbers too in many countries. Moreover, for example, the prefix for the Usa is 001 only 3 digits. Many times you find international prefix with a `+` because some operators want a `0` some other wants two `00`.

Comment: I have a phone that groups the cifers 4.3.3. The spaces are not relevant (in some old dialling program represented a pause in dialling). BTW I suggest you to chose `+` as representation of international `00` call, the spacing you find more right to help the client, and a checkbox to enter a non common number if it will happens.

Comment: @Hastur: I think that means your network operator defaults the country code to xxx format.

Comment: My UK landline and mobile number are both **14** digits when expressed in international format: 0044 151 xxx xxxx / 0044 7496 xxx xxx

Comment: Funny this [IBM page](http://www.ibm.com/contact/us/en/) remembered me another reasons why different grouping for the telephone numbers can be used... __because it is possible to memorize them as words__. E.g. [Word to Phone Number Converter](http://www.miniwebtool.com/word-to-phone-number-converter/?word=SHOP-IBM).

Comment: There is not a [minimum number of digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbering_plan#Private_numbering_plan): e.g. +49-681-302-0 is the Universität des Saarlandes official main number...  Big companies can handle private block as they wish. In some nation/cities till some time ago was still possible to find users with 7 or 8 digits in the same district...  I cannot say worldwide. (In real cases be ready to handle different lengths :) )

Answer (score 1):

Check the section 6.1 in the [Recommendation ITU-T E.164](https://www.itu.int/rec/dologin_pub.asp?lang=e&id=T-REC-E.164-201011-I!!PDF-E&type=items):

**SERIES E: OVERALL NETWORK OPERATION,
TELEPHONE SERVICE, SERVICE OPERATION AND
HUMAN FACTORS**

International operation – Numbering plan of the
international telephone service

It says:

**6.1 International ITU-T E.164-number length**

ITU-T recommends that the maximum number of digits for the international geographic, global
services, Network and groups of countries applications should be 15 (excluding the international
prefix). Administrations are invited to do their utmost to limit the digits to be dialled to the degree
possible consistent with the service needs.

---

It means that you have to count on 15 digits plus *international prefix* that in most countries is *00*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, can you give an example of public telephone number in 15 digits? If the web form would request my telephone number in 15-digits format I would be confused.

Comment: @Adobe It's UP TO 15, not exactly 15.